# Android Forensic Application

Tags: android, filesystems

I'm working on an Android Forensic application to retrieve deleted text messages, email and call history from any Android device. I managed to extract several deleted records from sqlite database using my C++ app however to get the sqlite dbs I should be connected to a rooted Android device which is practically not possible as the people who will be using this app doesn't have much technical expertise and they won't be able to root the device.

To work around this problem, I'm thinking about carving sqlites from file system images and I'm very confident of doing the same once I get access to the image files. So I tried dd and nanddump but it seems like they both need write access to the partitions to dump the images.

So I'd like to know whether there is a way to dump the userdata partition without su / root permission on the device?

Comment: Just curious how you've done on this. I just looked into carving some SQLite data (individual records since there appears to be some corruption) from an image from Android and it seems pretty difficult especially since SQLite uses data types that don't have fixed byte lengths - http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
An integer can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes for example. So how do you know how long each value is? Anyway, in the data I have, I'm not seeing it match up with the schema.